# Transfer Markers from MyMaps to QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-maps, kml, kmz

I've georeferenced a list of adresses on Google My Maps, I'd like to transfer them to QGIS so I can create a better map with them.

When I export a KML or KMZ file from My Maps and open it on QGIS, I only get a table containing the infos, not a vector o Shapefile, none of the addresses are georeferenced.

What could I do?

Thnks

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Could you explain your steps on exporting from Maps and importing in QGis in detail?

Comment: On the MyMaps editor, I click on Export to KMZ/KML, then I drag to file to QGIS

Comment: Have you tried importing into QGis using a dialogue? Have you tried using a different format for export/import (if there are some available, haven't used My Maps before)?

Comment: Yes I tried adding it as a vector or as a raster, and all I get is a table.

Comment: Mymaps only lets me export as KML/KMZ

Comment: Isnt there another way to georeference a list of of addresses?

Comment: Could you provide some sample-data?

Comment: I added some images explaining step by step what I did, I don't how to upload data here

Comment: How about you check the second tickbox when exporting your data? Did this, importing into QGis is no hassle.

Comment: Yes I exported to KML as well. Did it work with you ? Did the points for each address appear on the Qgis map?

Comment: Yes, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today as well. It looks like the KMZ exported from Google Maps only includes an "address" attribute for each Placemark and does not include a "point" attribute. Google is apparently not willing to share the output of their geocoding algorithm. I'm sorry to say I think you are out of luck and will need to geocode the addresses in some other way. Such as the MMQGIS plugin.